# Triangle area computation and linear transformations

Tags: python, unit-testing, matrix, computational-geometry

I have a task to learn how to write clear and understandable documentation of written code in python. Please, can you give me a feedback to attached code below? I need to know if the code and comments explains the functionality of code properly.

```
# math operations library
import numpy as np

# for testing of classes
import unittest

# ========================== NODE ==================================== #
#Class representing geometric node in 3D
class Node:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, z=0):
        self.X = x
        self.Y = y
        self.Z = z

# =========================== TRIANGLE =============================== #
# class representing triangle ABC
class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.A = a
        self.B = b
        self.C = c

    # returns area of triangle in 2D
    def Area(self):
        return (
                np.absolute(
                    self.A.X * (self.B.Y - self.C.Y)
                    + self.B.X * (self.C.Y - self.A.Y)
                    + self.C.X * (self.A.Y - self.B.Y)
                    ) / 2.0
                )

# unittests for triangle object
class TriangleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_area(self):
        # triangle node
        A = Node(0,0)
        B = Node(1,0)
        C = Node(0,1)

        T = Triangle(A,B,C)
        self.assertEquals(T.Area(), 0.5)

# ============================ Transformation ======================== #

"""
class representing transformation from reference triangle
with: A = [0,0],
      B = [1,0],
      C = [0,1].
"""
class Transformation:
    def __init__(self, triangle):
        # Base node - A node of triangle
        self.A = triangle.A

        # Matrix B(2x2) representing transformation operator
        self.B11 = triangle.B.X - triangle.A.X
        self.B12 = triangle.C.X - triangle.A.X
        self.B21 = triangle.B.Y - triangle.A.Y
        self.B22 = triangle.C.Y - triangle.A.Y

        # determinant of transformation = B matrix (2x2)
        self.Jacobian = (
                (self.B11 * self.B22) - (self.B21 * self.B12)
                )

        # Inverse of transformation operator = invB matrix (2x2)
        self.invB11 = 1 / self.Jacobian * (self.B22)
        self.invB12 = - 1 / self.Jacobian * (self.B12)
        self.invB21 = - 1 / self.Jacobian * (self.B21)
        self.invB22 = 1 / self.Jacobian * (self.B11)

    def TransformNode(self, node):
        """
        This function returns coordinates of node, that is transformed
        from referance coordinates system to general coordinate system
        of given 2D triangle.

        Args:

        * node - geometrical node with coordinates in reference system

        Returns:

        * node with transformed coordinates into general coordinates
        system of given 2D triangle
        """

        return Node(
                self.A.X + (self.B11 * node.X) + (self.B12 * node.Y),
                self.A.Y + (self.B21 * node.X) + (self.B22 * node.Y)
                )

    def InvTransformNode(self, node):
        """
        This function returns coordinates of node, thah is transformed
        from general coordinate system of given 2D triangle to refere-
        nce coordinate system.

        Args:

        * node - geometrical node with coordinates in general system

        Returns:

        * node with transformed coordinates to reference coordinate
        system
        """

        return Node(
                self.invB11 * (node.X - self.A.X)
                + self.invB12 * (node.Y - self.A.Y),
                self.invB21 * (node.X - self.A.X)
                + self.invB22 * (node.Y - self.A.Y)
                )

# unittests for transformation object
class TransformationTest(unittest.TestCase):
     def test_NodeTransformation(self):
         """
         Checking if node D is transformed to reference system and back
         correctly
         """

         # triangle nodes
         A = Node(1,1)
         B = Node(3,1)
         C = Node(4,2)

         # transformed node
         D = Node(2,3)

         T = Triangle(A,B,C)
         Trans = Transformation(T)

         # retransformed node D
         resD = Trans.TransformNode(Trans.InvTransformNode(D))

         # compare result coordinates
         self.assertEquals(resD.X, D.X)
         self.assertEquals(resD.Y, D.Y)


# ============================== testing ============================= #
# Test Triangle object
suite1 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TriangleTest)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=3).run(suite1)

# Test Transformation object
suite2 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TransformationTest)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=3).run(suite2)
```

Comment: (Welcome to CR!) Do you know [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring)s? That is one thing python got right: documentation amidst essential parts of code. This still gets out of sync, but separating it from the code would require extra/criminal energy.

Comment: Many thanks, it seem to be interesting, I will check it.

Comment: @VaPo not a large enough suggestion to be it's own answer, but use a `namedtuple` for the Node type - as in, `Node = namedtuple('Node', ['X', 'Y', 'Z'])`. It's shorter, clearer, and will provide you with some useful debugging stuff as well.

Comment: Even when it works for your example numbers, you should not check if a float is ``0.5``, but if ``abs(x-0.5) < eps``, e.g. with ``eps=1e-14``. Else there will be cases where floating point arithmetic leads to small rounding errors even when you think your numbers are even. I.e. you have ``0.1+0.2 == 0.30000000000000004`` in python.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answers, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are a few of the high- and low-level ideas:

- *too many comments.* Remember, comments tend to age and outdate, they need to be maintained as the code changes. And, if they are over-used, they hurt readability, not improve it. See more at [Coding Without Comments](https://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-without-comments/)
- convert some of the comments preceding the functions and methods to proper [documentation strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)
- there are some [PEP8 naming violations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) - like variable and function names that start with an upper case letter
- see if you can separate code from the tests into different files/modules
- if performance or/and memory usage is a concern, you may use [`__slots__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/472000/771848) for attribute definitions
- there is also this awesome [`attrs` library](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs) that may help with some class-attrs related boilerplate code

Comment: +1 on this. Instead of those huge distracting banner comments, just put every class in it's own file.

Answer (score 3):

The code is very readable and the comments are nice. Just a few remarks on some comments:

- Why don't `Node` and `Triangle` have docstring comments?
- Importing libraries doesn't need commentary.

Comment: Having `Node` and `Triangle` docstrings seems a bit meaningless since they're such obvious classes - you can digest the code in 3 seconds flat.

Comment: You could make it a one line docstring. I’ve seen getter functions with one line docstrings.

Comment: Well of course you *could*, but I don't really see the point of that.

Comment: I think just to have it in the documentation.

Comment: Mindlessly documenting doesn't do much good.

Comment: I like having it in there, but you don’t really need to.